# Setting and accessing variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
module YourApp
   class Application < Rails::Application
      config.my_custom_variable = :custom_value
   end
end
```

This works in my Rails application. I just want to understand how this works from ruby perspective. As per to my minimal ruby knowledge, there must be getter and setter(my_custom_variable=) for my_custom_variable in the config(Rails::Application::Configuration) object. Since this is my custom variable this will not be present in the Configuration object instance. How is it dynamically created/added. ?

Can somebody please explain?, direct me to the proper documentation to understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails is using `method_missing` here to catch any method called on `config`.
Then, it just adds it into a hash of options.

You can see the relevant source code [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/configuration.rb#l98).

Answer (score 0):

Not how Rails implements it, but achieve similar functionality in Ruby

```
require 'ostruct'

module YourApp
    class Application
        @@config = OpenStruct.new

        def self.config
           return @@config
        end
    end
end

YourApp::Application.config.my_custom_variable = :custom_value
puts YourApp::Application.config.my_custom_variable
>> custom_value
```